# Next.js + tRPC + response with cookie

Tags: cookies, next.js, trpc.io

I'm using Next.js 13 and tRPC 10. For auth purposes, I'm trying to create a specific tRPC endpoint which can set cookies.

I've looked over the [tRPC docs](https://trpc.io/docs/client/headers) but I'm still not clear on what to do.